# For loop in a batch for doing something in the actual path and in all subfolders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have to send several commands (`del`, compressing files, etc.) In a folder and its subfolders.

I'm using a for loop and now I'm able to send all the commands in all the subdirectory, but not in the actual path.

In the following what I'm doing (loops in the subfolder, enternig in them, extracting the extension of the files called `my-file.*`) and then doing several operations inside each subfolder (....),

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /o:n /ad') do (
REM "delims=" to deal with path containing spaces
cd /d "%%a"
for %%i in (my-file.*) do set EXTENSION=%%~xi
....
)
```

Comment: Why do you use two loops, why not simply using one: `for /R %%I in ("my-file.*") do echo "%%~xI" is the extension of file "%%~I".`

Comment: Because then I must send several commands to be executed in each subfolder

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong with your code based on the information you have provided.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, my code works, but only in each subfolder. I would like to have it running also in the current path

Comment: Then I don't see any reason why you can't use a `FOR /R` in your code as suggested previously.

Comment: Before you do anything else. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The current code features a loop to enumerate a directory tree, which contains another loop to enumerate the files per (sub-)directory, so using a single loop to enumerate all files in the directory tree immediately would do fine; anyway, it would be helpful to know what commands you are trying to do... and by the way, please follow Squashman's advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `('dir /s /b /o:n /ad')` use  `('cd ^& dir /s /b /o:n /ad')`

Comment: I tried to use that command but he returns me something like: "& unattended"

Comment: @Filippo, i edited my answer, `^` should be added before `&` when it's in a `for` loop

Comment: That's doing exactly what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a `for /F` loop with `dir /S` command which searches through all subfolders:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /S /B /A-D "my-file.*"') do (
    pushed "%%~dpA"
    rem do random stuff here
    popd
)
```

Note that you don't need to set to a variable the extension, you can access it with `%%~xA` immediately.

I have enabled delayed expansion since you may set a variable inside the `for` loop, so you will need to access it with `!var!` rather than `%var%`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use `forfiles` as in following example:

```
forfiles /s /M my_file.* /C "cmd /c echo @file:@path,@fname.@ext"

"my_file.log":"C:\tralala\my_file.log","my_file"."log"
"my_file.txt":"C:\tralala\my_file.txt","my_file"."txt"
```

Comment: Note that `forfiles` enumerates both files and directories; use the meta-variable `@isdir` to distinguish between them (see `forfiles /?`)...